# Patient or client?

Tags: word-usage, difference

I know that this is subjective and opinions may vary, but do you prefer "patients" or "clients" about people who are seeing a psychologist? And the same question with psychiatrist.

Comment: *Patients* definitely. We are visiting a doctor after all. In both cases if I must use it.

Comment: People visiting psychologists or psychiatrists may well prefer 'client', because to be a 'patient' of such professionals may bring thoughts in others of erratic behaviour, and the wearing of what Charles Dickens called a 'strait-waistcoat'.

Comment: Traditionally, those treated by psychiatrists & clinical psychologists were referred to as patients, while those who received mental-health counseling from therapists who lacked medical training (e.g., social workers) were likelier to be called clients. Recently, an increasing number of medical practitioners prefer to call those they treat "clients." There's a great deal more behind this shift than a desire to avoid the evoking the kind of crude stereotypes Michael Harvey mentions; among other things, some see the term "client" as more empowering to the recipient of care.

Comment: In many British contexts, we no longer say "mental patient", we say "client of the mental health services".

Answer (score 1):

You are a patient of a doctor or psychiatrist or psychologist, clincally.

Business-wise (they have to make a living!), you are a client.

Comment: For the US, at least, this answer doesn't reflect common usage at all. Psychiatrists and other practitioners who use the term "patient" for those they treat use it in both the clinical and the business context. They do **not** say "I'm very concerned about that patient's lack of progress" and then turn around and say "That client still hasn't paid his bill."

Comment: @Nanigashi I never implied what you suggest. I am merely saying that in healthcare business lingo patients are in fact clients.

Comment: Oh, I was just giving one representative example; perhaps it wasn't the best one. What I was getting at is that in my experience, if the caregivers in a given setting refer to those in their care as "patients," pretty much **everyone** involved in the practice, very much including the "business" side (billing department employees, schedulers, administrators, etc.), will follow suit, in all contexts. Sorry I wasn't clearer! (I have no idea in what venues this "healthcare business lingo" you refer to might be used or how it's relevant to the OP; you might want to edit your answer to clarify.)

Answer (score 1):

I have a cousin living in the UK who is a social therapist, and she calls them "clients".

Yes, I was also surprised when I first heard that. However, I think the term "client" helps the person in therapy to be less emotionally attached and dependent on their therapist leading to a greater sense of autonomy. A psychologist or psychiatrist who calls someone seeking their help "a patient", may suggest that he or she is either sick or needs to be admitted in hospital.

The term *client* was used 18 times, compared to *patient* which was used only 5 times, in the  article below. Paradoxically, the two terms appear to be interchangeable in this excerpt.

> Many [social therapists **work with clients**](https://www.psychologyschoolguide.net/therapist-careers/how-can-you-become-a-social-therapist/#:%7E:text=Social%20therapists%20are%20highly%20educated,and%20licensed%20mental%20health%20counselor.) to help them cope with and overcome life’s issues. Social therapists do this by listening to their **patients**, assessing their needs, and working with the **client** to create a coping strategy. These professionals often work in close collaboration with other mental health professionals including counselors, marriage and family therapists, psychologists, social workers, and psychiatrists. […]

> Social therapists help their **clients** get along in the world. Social therapists are highly educated and trained specialists who **help their clients** face and cope effectively with such issues as relationships, depression and anxiety, marital discord, stress, grief, trauma and the like.

Comment: Yes, therapists do say clients. And I dunno about saying that psychiatrists and psychologists wouldn't say patient as it implies admission to hospital.

Answer (score 1):

While person-centered psychologists first suggested the adoption of the term "client" to avoid the supposed negative connotation of "patient", research actually suggests that people in therapy overwhelmingly prefer to be referred to as patients (Christmas & Sweeney, 2016). It seems that mental health professionals adopted this term without really considering what people in treatment want to be referred as, which is kind of ironic since the entire purpose of using the term "client" was to give people in treatment more autonomy.

As a therapist, I treat patients since patients in any level of care ought to **always** be an active collaborator in their treatment. I am not giving a service, I am working with my patient to improve their health; just because it is their mental health does not mean that treatment for it should be reduced to a mere service.